# Is there any way to create a customized view in lotus notes that shows unread mail only?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I am looking to create a view that shows only Unread Email (existing and upcoming). This can be done using a built-in feature with notes client in Inbox. However, I need it in my own customized view.

Answer (score 2):

You can call @ViewShowThisUnread("1"). It shows unread documents only.

I'd put this code into an action button so user can decide what to see: all or unread documents only.

It should work in PostOpen event too. This way it would reduce visible document to unread only right after opening the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is possible, at least the way I read your question.

The Inbox is not a view, it's a folder.  Views (even custom ones) can be set to show only Unread (it's on the Beanie tab in the view properties) but I wasn't able to find any @Formula that could be used to select unread documents.

As an alternative, you can add code to the form (like in the QueryOpen event) that sets a field in the document flagging it as "read" and then use that in your @Select formula.